dynamic creation of function with @action decorator in ModelViewSet in Django
currently in my ModelViewSet i have defined a function with the action-decorator as follows:
@action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
def calculate_something(self, request, **kwargs):
     ... do something

     task = calculate_fit_limits.delay(object_id)

     ... do some more stuff
     return Response({'task_id': task_id})

now, all the parts with ... do something are similar for other but similar actions i want to define that way. the only thing which changes is the function, which i call as
task = calculate_fit_limits.delay(object_id)

therefore i thought of writing a parent ViewSet, which takes care of creating dynamically the functions including the action-decorator.
here is my current implementation for the parent viewset
class BaseTaskViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    task_functions = {}  # Expected to be a dict, mapping task names to functions

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.register_task_actions()

    def register_task_actions(self):
        for task_name, functions in self.task_functions.items():
            self.add_task_action(
                task_name, functions['calculate'])

    def add_task_action(self, task_name, calculate_func):
        # Dynamic method for calculating task limits
        def calculate(self, request, **kwargs):
            ... do something
            task = calculate_func.delay(object_id)
            
            ... do something

            return Response({'task_id': task_id})

        # set the name
        calculate.__name__ = f'calculate_{task_name}'


        # apply the decorator
        calculate_method = action(detail=True, methods=[
                                  'get'])(calculate)

        setattr(self, calculate.__name__, calculate_method)

finally, in my child viewset i want to create actions as follows:
class MyViewSet(BaseTaskViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModel

    task_functions = {
        'action_name': {
            # Your task function for calculating fit limits
            'calculate': some_function,
        },
    }

so with that approach, i indeed create a function with the correct name:
calculate.__name__ = f'calculate_{task_name}

which i verified by listing in MyViewSet
print((dir(self))

however, the endpoint for that function is not available, which should be the case when using the action-decorator.
i checked the action-decorator function itself but dont understand it sufficiently when/how the action-decorator takes care so that the function is added to the view/url-pattern...
is there something i am missing?
in my opinion it would me a nice and elegant way to register the tasks for the ModelViewSet and therefore i wanted to ask here before i search for alternative solutions.
it is noted that the original function in MyViewSet like that
@action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
def calculate_something(self, request, **kwargs):

is working, so the urls are set up correctly.
